# NoClassDefFoundError after updating Gradle 2.1.0 to 2.2.1

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin

I have libraries which are aar files. After changing root gradle classpath 2.1.0 to 2.2.1, i get NoClassDefFoundError errors.

For example : I create a new class in my aar library after that i sync and my main app see my class but when i run application, in runtime it gives me NoClassDefFoundError.

Ps : After updating, gradle downloaded 2.14.1.

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ca8b20)
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gk.lib.ui.Utils
:     at com.example.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in my MainActivity class i call method with static method like that :

```
Utils.gkTestMethod();
```

My Utils Class :

```
import android.util.Log;

public class Utils {

    public static void gkTestMethod(){
        Log.v("Log","Log");
    }
}
```

Doesn't matter what is the class which i called. If I create new class, it gives this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: i updated my question. You can see.@Jens

Comment: What is in your MainActivity.java file, line 78?

Comment: @AleksG i added my class.

Comment: This means that the compiler cannot find class `Utils`

Comment: Not compiler, it is not found in runtime. Code build successfully after app is running when it call Utils or something which new created in aar library, it gives NoClassDeffoundError

Comment: please post `build.gradle`s of both main app and aar

Comment: i updated my post @nandsito

Answer (score 0):

About this snippet in the main `build.gradle`:

> ```
> dependencies {
>
>     compile('com.gk.lib:common:1.0.0') {
>         transitive = true
>     }
>
>     compile('com.gk.lib:ui:1.0.0') {
>         transitive = true
>         exclude module: 'common'
>     }
>
>     compile('com.gk.lib:components:1.0.0') {
>         transitive = true
>         exclude module: 'common'
>         exclude module: 'ui'
>     }
>
>     // Other dependencies
> }
> ```

It seems that `components` depends on `common` and `ui`, and `ui` depends on `common`. Is there a good reason for explicitly excluding and then reincluding the transitive dependencies? I think this should work:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.gk.lib:components:1.0.0'

    // Other dependencies
}
```

And IIRC `common` is not transitive.

Comment: I didn't put compile debug and release common dependicies. I changed my post, you can see new version. I divide common dependency because i need to include some c file on debug or release and these are different.

Comment: @GörkemKaradoğan please add the complete and unmodified `build.gradle` of each library

Comment: i changed my post, as i said that all libraries gradle are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that multidex support solves my problem. Why am i not think that before :/ Thanks.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html